# Separable polynomial mod $\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/L$ be a galois extension with $L = K(\alpha)$ and let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $p$ be the prime number above which $\mathfrak{p}$ lies. How does the fact that $f$ is separable mod $\mathfrak{p}$ relate to the fact that $ p$  does not divide $[\mathcal{O}_L : \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]]$ ?

I ask this because I have seen both as an hypothesis for the same result e.g. proposition 5.11 in Cox primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$ opposed to theorem $27$ in Number fields of Marcus. Note though that in Cox the extension is galois and not in Marcus .

Comment: No one has an idea ?